# symfony2 link a file to server

Tags: jquery, symfony

I have PDF files hosted on the server. Could I open those files by pressing a button with Symfony2? The path to those files will be housed in an entity in the database. Pressing the button by AJAX gets the path in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it that's what you're looking for but `AJAX` cannot handle file download by itself. The closest match would be to send AJAX request that would build file path which would then be returned to view.

Let's assume you're using JSON as a manner of trasporing data back to view..

Then, you either redirect using:

```
window.location.href = response.path;
```

where `response` is `JSON` object returned from controller

or set `src` attribute of some, previously created, `iframe` tag:

```
$('#myDocumentIframe').attr('src', response.path);
```

Is this what you trying to achieve?